# Can't create files in a specific folder from the given list

Tags: java, file, oop

Can anyone explain why this code wont work? Why is it not creating the files in the given destination? Instead it just ouputs the groupId and not created statement.

Any help or guidance would be highly appreciated.

```
        List<String> groupList = userGroupAuthor.getPredefinedGroupList();
        String groupId; 

        for (String groupName : groupList) {
            groupId = StringHelper.makeGroupId(groupName);
            System.out.println(groupId);
            //writeGroupName(groupId, groupName);
            File f = new File(testScriptName);
            try{
                boolean fvar = f.createNewFile();
                if(fvar){
                    System.out.println("File Created");
                }else {

                    System.out.println("Not Created");
                }
            }           

            //bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f));
     catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: How is this related to C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood the question, it is why the same filename `testScriptName` is resulting in a "Not Created" message on each run.

The [JavaDoc for File.createNewFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html) states:

> Atomically creates a new, empty file named by this abstract pathname **if and only if** a file with this name does not yet exist. The check for the existence of the file and the creation of the file if it does not exist are a single operation that is atomic with respect to all other filesystem activities that might affect the file. [emphasis added]

Since the same filename is being used inside the loop, it will fail if the file already exists, which it would after the first run.

To resolve the situation, either move the file creation outside of the loop, or use a unique filename for each group. There is insufficient provided logic in the code to determine the intent.